# How can I mathematically show that multiplication of j will cause a phase shift?

Tags: math, phase, phase-shift, phasor

I have a simple question that I cannot seem to wrap my head around.
let's say I have a function A*sin(w*t), if I multiply a '-j' by this function to get:

-j*A*sin(w*t), I have been told that this is essentially a phase shift by negative 90 degrees.

So essentially the result is cos(w*t)

Thinking in terms of microwave 90degree hybrids entire S parameter matrix's claim that multiplying by 'j' will cause a phase shift.

I can't seem to prove mathematically why this is though as when I apply Euler's formula:

e^(jθ) = cos(θ) + j sin(θ)

I get -j*A*sin(w*t) = A*cos(w*t)-A*e^(jw*t)

Can someone help me mathematically show that a multiplication of j will cause a phase shift? Or am I completely wrong altogether?

EDIT: this is my math so far:

Convert sin to cos with an argument:
-j*sin(wt) = e^(-j*pi/2)*cos(w*t-pi/2)

cos(w*t-pi/2) is the Real[e^j(wt-pi/2)]

so e^(-j*pi/2)*e^j(wt-pi/2)=e^(j(wt-pi)). looking at only the real part of this

is -cos(wt)

Comment: Can I assume that you already *do* understand that if you take (1+2j) as a vector on the complex plane and multiply that by j to get (-2+1j), that the new vector will be at 90 degrees counterclockwise with respect to the original vector? There's more to follow that and some reasoning with respect to their application in electronics. But if that first bit isn't clear, then the rest will be a bit of a slog. (I've not considered your starting statement. So I may find something wrong with your logic starting there when and if I take a moment for that.) First things first, though.

Comment: @periblepsis Yes I understand this result, but surely the shift in the real complex plane does not translate to a phase shift of sine : sine(wt-theta). If I have -j*sin(wt) this is a sine wave that is purely imaginary. How is that a real cosine? -cos(wt). Surely j*sin(wt) != cos(wt) as this disagrees with Euler formula

Comment: Let me jump forward a little as another probe. Try out this statement: *Vectors are not just lists of numbers. All lists of numbers are vectors. But not all vectors are lists of numbers. Vectors can be functions.* Does this also make sense to you?

Comment: @periblepsis Sure, but I am not seeing what you are getting at.

Comment: If you did, by definition, you wouldn't be asking the question you are asking. Sine and cosine functions can be used for forming an orthogonal (if not orthonormal) basis set that uniquely (maximally?) spans a space. Can you tell me what exactly you were reading to place down this question in the first place? Context may help me. I'm just trying to consider what and how to write when I have a moment.

Comment: @periblepsis  I have a 90degree hybrid microwave circuit I am doing analysis on. I have an AC voltage A*sin(w*t) as input. Going into the s-parameter matrix, the voltage at the output of port three, would be equal to -j*A*sin(w*t). many literatures cite this as a phase shift. doing Euler's equation simply doesn't show this.

Comment: @Jirhska, you don't multiply the time-domain representation by *j*, you need to convert to a phasor representation first. See my latest edit.

Comment: @Jirhska Then this sounds to me (I'm ignorant on your topic, keep in mind) like what I was hand-waving at: namely a use of orthogonal trig functions as a basis set representing signals. You have some answers that don't appear to go there. So if I'm guessing right, I'm not sure they will be helpful. If you find they actually are helpful, then that's that - I'm wrong - and we break company. If still not, though, and if I'm thinking in the right direction (but ignorant of your field, keep in mind) then a different discussion may follow. But perhaps better done at the math site than here.

Answer (score 4):

I think that confusion could be related with the two possible methods for representing **sinusoidal** time varying signals associated with the complex plane:

**1. AS COMPLEX NUMBERS**

This form is close related to a two terms Fourier series decomposition for sinusiodal signals. The "vector" resulting from summing two complex exponentials, rotating in **opposite directions**, has a time varying magnitude and describes a trajectory along a straight line in complex plane.

First, consider the following plot for \$\sin(\omega t)\$:

[image]

The next animation shows an alternative representation for that "vector" summ (non  centered at origin). This version is prefered in diagrams showing several Fourier terms, with multiple harmonics, which I'm gonna use on the next animations here:

[image]

The representation for \$cos(\omega t)\$ below, looks like that for \$\sin(\omega t)\$, but note that, for instance when \$\omega t = 0\$ rad, the positions are \$(1,0)\$ and \$(0,0)\$) respectively:

[image]

So far, I've shown only real valued signals. Next, it's worth to noting that \$-j\sin(\omega t)\$, does not represent a physical signal. For this reason, in most cases, the coeficients in Fourier series expansion appear as **pairs of complex conjugates** values that, when summed up, generate the real valued terms. A similar argument is applicable to Fourier Transform, too.

So:

$$-j\sin(\omega t)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-j\omega t} - \frac{1}{2}e^{j\omega t}$$

The animation below shows that, multiplying the real signal \$\sin(\omega t)\$ by \$-j\$, causes a shift by 90\${^\circ}\$ clockwise (-90\${^\circ}\$), transforming it in a signal with imaginary component only.

[image]

Therefore:

$$-j\sin(\omega t) \neq \cos(\omega t)$$

Now, let me show you a more elaborated signal that results from shifting  \$\sin(\omega t\$) by 30\${^\circ}\$ counterclockwise. In other words, multiplying it by the complex \$e^{j\frac{\pi}{6}}\$ or \$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+j0.5\$:

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+j0.5\right)\sin(\omega t)=$$
$$e^{j\frac{\pi}{6}}\sin(\omega t)=$$
$$e^{j\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{1}{j2}\left(e^{j\omega t}-e^{-j\omega t} \right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[e^{j(\omega t-\frac{\pi}{3})}-e^{-j(\omega t+\frac{\pi}{3})} \right]$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[e^{j(\omega t-\frac{\pi}{3})}+e^{-j(\omega t-\frac{2\pi}{3})} \right]$$

[image]

**2. AS DECOMPOSITION OF ROTATING PHASORS**

This representation is used in literature when discussing phasors related to AC circuits. The related time varying signals are always real, resulting from taking the real (\$Re\left\{.\right\}\$) or the imaginary component (\$Im\left\{.\right\}\$) from rotating phasors (here I take the real components). These phasors rotate in the **same direction** due the fact it are different entities - with no summation.
The animation below shows the 90\${^\circ}\$ shifting between \$\cos(\omega t)\$ and \$\sin(\omega t)\$ (or \$\cos(\omega t-\frac{\pi}{2})\$):

[image]

Finally, a 30\${^\circ}\$ shifting between two waveforms:

[image]

I think this second form relating sinusiodal signals with the complex plane is the most useful and the one you are interested in.

Comment: very nice, what did you use to do the cool animations?

Comment: It can be done, for example, using desmos, Python (matplotlib, manim,...), Matlab, Scilab, Mathematica, Maple and others.

Answer (score 1):

> e^(jθ) = cos(θ) + j sin(θ)

> I get -jAsin(wt) = Acos(wt)-Ae^(jw*t)

You might be better off going to

$$ \sin\theta = \frac{e^{j\theta}-e^{-j\theta}}{2j}$$

However this is not going to get you to \$j\sin\theta = \cos\theta\$ if that's what you mean by a phase shift. It can't get there because \$\cos\theta\$ is always real and \$j\sin\theta\$ is always complex, so they absolutely can't be equal.

---

That said, if your function \$A\sin(\omega t)\$ is meant to be a phasor representing a voltage or current in AC steady state, then all you need to know is that when multiplying complex numbers,

$$\angle AB = \angle A + \angle B$$

and therefore any time you multiply a phasor by \$j\$, which has angle \$90^\circ\$, you always advance the phase by \$90^\circ\$, regardless of what you started with.

---

Edit to add: In comments you asked,

> can I be annoying and ask for a derivation OR a pointer to a derivation that allows us to add the angle?

The easy way is to write your phasors in exponential functions like

$$ a + jb = r e^{j\theta} $$

But be careful, the \$\theta\$ in this formula is not the argument of the sine function in your \$A\sin(\omega t)\$. You should be writing

$$ A \sin(\omega t) = A \sin(\omega t) e^{j0}$$,

then you multiply by \$j\$:

$$ (j)(A \sin(\omega t)) = (1 e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}})(A \sin(\omega t) e^{j0})$$
$$  = A \sin(\omega t) e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Now you can see the phase term (the argument of the exponential) has increased from 0 to \$\frac{\pi}{2}\$, meaning the phase of the phasor has advanced in phase.

Of course you could also just recognize that \$jA\sin(\omega t)\$ is a purely imaginary number, and therefore is always 90 degrees advanced from \$A\sin(\omega t)\$ which is a purely real number.

---

Maybe the real answer:

It seems likely that what has really happened here is you are mixing up the time domain and phasor representations of your signal, and when you treat your signal \$A\sin(\omega t)\$ as a phasor, the phasor value should be \$1 + j0\$. The angle of this phasor is 0.

Now when you "multiply by *j*" you do this in the phasor domain and get \$j(1 + j0)\$, which is \$0 + j1\$. And this has an angle of \$\pi/2\$ radians or \$90^\circ\$, which is 90 degrees advanced from the phasor you started with.

Comment: This is good, but can I be annoying and ask for a derivation OR a pointer to a derivation that allows us to add the angle? I listed some math in my Original question regarding only taking the real part of the [e^j(wt-pi/2)] which would show that jsinθ=cosθ. But I need to know why this is a reality. Maybe I am forgetting something elementary here.

Comment: You can write a complex number \$a+jb\$ as \$re^{j\theta}\$. But when you start with \$A\sin(\omega t)\$ you don't have \$\theta = \omega t\$. You have \$r=A\sin(\omega t)\$ and \$\theta = 0\$ because you are startingn with a real number (\$b=0\$).

Comment: maybe the question is "Why can a phasor be used to represent a time domain phase shift of a signal, AND why is it only for AC voltage/current functions?"

Comment: That would be a separate question, but the answer is basically "because the math works out".

Comment: I should add: 1. Please review the Wikipedia [phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) article first, if you are considering submitting this "big" question. 2. The concept can be extended to non-AC-steady-state solutions in [Laplace analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Examples_and_applications).

Comment: However all this is to say that Re[ j*sin(θ)*e^(j0) ] = cos(θ).  Essentially when I consider the phasor representation I should be considering the Real portion as j*sin(θ) will never = cosine

Comment: I'm worried that since I misunderstood your question, my answer has just added more confusion. You should review phasor representations in your favorite text or Wiki article.

Comment: I understand your answer, what I have gotten from this is that Phasor representation allows for time invariant AC voltages and currents to be represented with complex mathematics. For mathematics j*sinθ != cosθ. However if j and sinθ are phasors then the result will be a cos θ. This is because  -j*sin(wt) = e^(-jpi/2)*cos(wt-pi/2)= e^(-jpi/2)*Real[e^j(wt-pi/2)]=e^(j(wt-pi)). Now since I took the real part I am only 'interested' in the real part ->  = -cos(wt). looking at only the real part of this is the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In the complex plane, the unit vector j is expressed in polar coordinates as 1∠90°.

Comment: yet this would be a phase shift to the function of sin(w*t) not a phase shift to the argument of the sin(w*t) input

Comment: @Jirhska You're going to have to explain what you mean by that.  How do you define "a phase shift to the function of sin(ωt)" and "a phase shift to the argument of the sin(ωt) input"? How are they different?

Comment: @Hearth j*sin(wt) is a purely imaginary function so the real sin(wt) has been shifted 90degrees in the real complex plane. A phase shift to the argument would be sin(wt-pi/2) which would =cos(wt),

Answer (score 0):

This is where complex numbers in polar form shine. Let \$r\angle\theta\$ represent the number \$ r e^{j \theta} = r (\sin \theta + j \cos \theta)\$. Then \$\left(a \angle \alpha\right) \cdot \left(b \angle \beta\right) = \left(a\cdot b\right) \angle \left(\alpha + \beta\right)\$. This is a useful thing to remember about complex multiplication in general: you multiply the magnitudes and add the arguments.

If you want to prove that statement, you can either use the definition of \$r\angle\theta\$ and the angle-sum identities for \$\sin\$ and \$\cos\$ (just expand both sides out until they're identical, remembering that \$j^2 = {-}1\$) or you can use the exponential identity \$e^x e^y = e^{x+y}\$ to show that \$\left(a\, e^{j \alpha}\right) \cdot \left(b\, e^{j \beta}\right) = ab\, e^{j\left(\alpha + \beta\right)}\$

Since \${-}j = 1\angle {-}90^{\circ}\$, it follows that \${-}j \cdot \left(r\angle\theta\right) = r\angle\left(\theta - 90^{\circ}\right)\$